# Why is the ILS 36R approach at ZBAA over twice as long as a standard ILS approach?

Tags: approach, ils, china

I fly exclusively in a consumer flight simulator, so excuse me if there's an obvious answer to this.

ILS approach plates typically show a long, arrow-like symbol to indicate the part of an approach path where the localizer and glideslope signals can be captured by an approaching aircraft; most often, when there are no natural or manmade obstacles, for 3º glideslopes, this is about 9nm out from the threshold and 3000ft above the touchdown zone.

Looking at a chart for ZBAA's ILS 36R approach (which I'm not sure I can include in this post since this would likely violate Navigraph and/or Jeppesen's ToS), 36R specifically has this arrow extend out twice as far as either 01 or 36L — to about 25.5nm and 6890ft above the deck.

Why is this, and how common are such extended ILS approaches elsewhere in the world?

Comment: The other two ILS approaches for the parallel runways (36L and 01) also show the same long arrow on their respective charts. They all show the arrows of the other ILS approaches much shorter on their charts (I guess to avoid overlap).